# Modulo operation property

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $x =(a+b) \pmod m$

and we know  `$(a+b)\pmod n=(a \pmod n+b \pmod n) \pmod n$

Can we write: $b = (x-a \pmod m)%m$

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Probably $m \equiv n$ ?

Comment: A residue `mod m` can be chosen in various ways, and mathematicians usually prefer to consider the *equivalence class* of these residues rather than (as software generally does) by designating a particular number as the result of the "modulo" operation `%`.  It is unclear what sense you have intended here, especially as both `%` and `mod` are mentioned.

Comment: @hardmath edited please check !!!

Comment: Isnt it just $(a+b)\pmod n=a \pmod n+b \pmod n$?

Comment: @1234: That doesn't work if the "mod" operator picks a single value (typical in software implementations).  For example, `1 (mod 2) + 1 (mod 2)` is not `2 (mod 2)` if the latter is supposed to be zero.

Comment: @adas:  So far as "solving" for $b$, we cannot determine a single answer since replacing $b$ by $b+m$ in the first equation would result in the same value of $X$.  Information about $b$ has been lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting this question to say

> Let $\newcommand{\R}{\operatorname{R}} \R : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the remainder function, so that $\R(a,b)$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$.
>
> Note that $\R$ satisfies $\R(a+b,n) = \R(\R(a,n) + \R(b,n),n)$ for all $a,b,n$.
>
> If $\R(a+b,m) = x$, then do we know $b = \R(x-a,m)$?

This remainder function (which you write "mod") is not preferred by mathematicians because it is clunky.  Rather, mathematicians speak of *equivalence* modulo $n$, which we define by $a \equiv b$ ($a$ equivalent to $b$ mod $n$) if and only if $\R(a,n) = \R(b,n)$.

Anyway, the answer to your question is yes, assuming that $b$ is between $0$ and $m$.
If $b$ is not between $0$ and $m$, you must say instead that $\R(b, m) = \R(x-a,m)$, which is to say, $b \equiv x - a \pmod{m}$.